# Cloning my Asus RT-N66R Wireless to a Cisco Aironet 1130AG

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-bridge, bridge-router

I want to use the Cisco Aironet as a network bridge and use it to just boost the original network. I ended up having to just disable my Asus radio and start an entirely new network on the Cisco.

Is this possible? Can anyone help me out with this?